# tshark - help finding tshark 1.6.7 field names

Tags: wireshark, tshark, network-analysis

Trying to convert pcap to txt and showing specific fields.

On thsark 1.12.4 this works:

> tshark -nr "input_file.pcap" -E header=y -e frame.number -e frame.time
>   -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e  _ws.col.Protocol -e _ws.col.Info -e data -T fields -V "tcp or udp" > "output_file.txt"

Sadly, on tshark 1.6.7 (which is kind of mendatory) the **protocol** and **info** cols don't show.

I've tried all the combinations I could find online: _ws.col.Info, _ws.col.info, col.Info, col.info, Info, info.

Couldn't find anything else.

Any suggestions how to make those cols to show in the ouptput txt file?

Best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any suggestions how to make those cols to show in the ouptput txt file?

Talk to whoever is in charge of making 1.6.7 mandatory, convince them *not* to make it mandatory, and then upgrade to a newer version of Wireshark.  That feature - the ability to show columns with `-T fields` - didn't *exist* in 1.6.x; it was added later, in the 1.10 release, as [the Bugzilla entry for the enhancement request for it](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2892) indicates.